# how to sort array based on key which is different

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have array object

```
var myObj = [
    {'week2Volume': 'asdsadfd'},
    {'week1Volume': 'masdasaf'},
    {'week3Volume': 'dsfdsfsdf'}
  ]
```

how to sort this based on key
I mean I want result as

```
var myObj = [
    {'week1Volume': 'masdasaf'},
    {'week2Volume': 'asdsadfd'},    
    {'week3Volume': 'dsfdsfsdf'}
  ]
```

What I tried -

```
_.sortBy(myObj, function(o) { return o.toLowerCase();   })
```

I am using underscore Please suggest me any solution. Any JavaScript native solution is also fine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
_.mixin({
    'sortKeysBy': function (obj, comparator) {
        var keys = _.sortBy(_.keys(obj), function (key) {
            return comparator ? comparator(obj[key], key) : key;
        });

        return _.object(keys, _.map(keys, function (key) {
            return obj[key];
        }));
    }
});
```

And then:

```
var obj = {b: 3, c: 2, a: 1};

_.sortKeysBy(obj);
// {a: 1, b: 3, c: 2}

_.sortKeysBy(obj, function (value, key) {
    return value;
});
// {a: 1, c: 2, b: 3}
```

Source: [gist](https://gist.github.com/colingourlay/82506396503c05e2bb94)

---

**Update**:
You have an array, not an object. So you can sort it without any addons.

```
_.sortBy(myObj, function(o) { 
  // return Object.keys(o)[0];
  return _.keys(o)[0];
});
```

Comment: For me.. object is like this.. var obj = [ { b : 3}, { c : 2 }, { a : 1} ]

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore's documentation on `sortBy()`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy):

> Returns a (stably) sorted copy of list, ranked in ascending order by the *results of running each value through iteratee*.

*(Emphasis mine)*

The iterator should return the key to sort by:

```
_.sortBy(myObj, function(o){ return _.keys(o)[0]; })
```

This returns the expected object by filtering by the first key.

---

`_.keys(o);` actually returns an array of keys. If you expect more keys and like to limit the keys to be sorted by, you may pass the result to `_.filter()`:

```
_.sortBy(myObj, function(o) {
    // filter the set of keys
    return _.filter(_.keys(o), function(key) {
        // filter key by this matcher
        return /^week[0-9]+Volume$/.test(key);
    })[0];
});
```

This way it gives the same result for

```
var myObj = [
        {'b': 1, 'week2Volume': 'asdsadfd'},
        {'c': 2, 'week1Volume': 'masdasaf'},
        {'a': 3, 'week3Volume': 'dsfdsfsdf'}
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javscript's sort function to sort your array as below.

```
var myObj = [
    {'week2Volume': 'asdsadfd'},
    {'week1Volume': 'masdasaf'},
    {'week3Volume': 'dsfdsfsdf'}
];

var sorted = myObj.sort(function (a, b) {
    return Object.keys(a)[0] > Object.keys(b)[0];
});

//This is the sorted array
console.dir(sorted);
```

Hope this helps. If any questions please ask.